# Android Cannot resolve symbol OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments, gps

I am new to android and I am trying to build an app to show my current location and I am following the setup in apidemos from google linked [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MyLocationDemoActivity.java). This is part of an assignment so I do not want to disclose what my ultimate goal is. For now I want to be able to have gps location working on my app. I will post my activity code, xml layout code, manifest code and gradle code. If there is anything else I need to post please let me know. I have tried searching but I couldn't find anything. Also if it helps I am mainly making this for my phone. Nexus 6p Android 6.0.1

EDIT:Got OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback Working but still have PermissionUtils giving me an error.

I will comment where my errors/cannot resolves are occurring

XML Code

```xml
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/StartButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:text="@string/Start"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:onClick="start"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/StopButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:text="@string/Stop"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:onClick="stop"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CameraButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:text="@string/Camera"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="107dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="openCamera"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ShareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:text="@string/Share"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</fragment>
```

Here is my activity

```java
package com.example.name.app;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.content.Intent;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.widget.Button;



public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback { //ERROR on OnRequest...CallBack
    /**
     * Request code for location permission request.
     *
     * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
     */
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    /**
     * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
     * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
     */
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    Button startbutton;
    Button stopbutton;
    Button sharebutton;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        startbutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
        stopbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
        sharebutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ShareButton);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Venice, Italy, and move the camera.
        /* LatLng venice = new LatLng(45.43, 12.33);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(venice).title("Marker in Venice"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(venice));*/

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        enableMyLocation();
    }

    private void enableMyLocation() {
        //ERROR CANNOT RESOLVE METHOD checkSelfPermission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            //ERROR CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL PermissionUtils
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }
        //ERROR CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL PermissionUtils

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }
    //ERROR CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL PermissionUtils

    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    public void start(View view){
        startbutton.setText("Running");
        stopbutton.setText("Stop");
    }
    public void stop(View view){
        stopbutton.setText("Stopped");
        startbutton.setText("Start");
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        //Get location and store it
        File storageDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/MyMap"); //Saves it in Pictures/MyMapp  but can only be viewd from file explorer
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
    public void openCamera(View view) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                galleryAddPic();
            }
        }
    }
    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

}
```

Here is my android manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.name.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"> </uses-permission>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my updated build gradle

```gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.name.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: can you change compilesdkversion and targetsdk version to 23?

Comment: @RavjitSingh How exactly would I do that. Would I right click and open module settings and change it that way?

Comment: no, in the gradle file, the last file that you have posted in ur question

Comment: @RavjitSingh I have changed it to what you have directed. I will update play services and report back soon. I shall be on in about half an hour (class now). Thank you for your help thus far

Comment: @RavjitSingh The onRequestPermissionsResultCallback no longer gives me an error however I still have PermissionUtils that gives me an error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade:

- `compileSdkVersion` to `23`
- `buildToolsVersion` to `23.0.2`
- `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` and `com.android.support:support-v13` to `23.2.0`

Your missing symbol is from a 23.x.y edition of `appcompat-v7`; the other changes are to keep the major version in sync.

Also, note that `7.5.0` is a rather old edition of `play-services`; I recommend upgrading that to `8.4.0`.

And, bear in mind that all your runtime permission stuff is pointless, given `targetSdkVersion 22`.

Comment: Hi, I changed the first two bullet points as you have directed. I am not totally sure what you mean by the third one. I am sorry, I am quite new to this. My targetsdkversion is 23 now. And I will update my play services in about an hour as I have class now. I will be back on soon. Thanks for the help

Comment: @SamuelJacksonJr: "I am not totally sure what you mean by the third one" -- it refers to two of the `dependencies` that you have in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Hey, I attached my updated build.gradle file which contains all of the recommended changes. The onRequestPermissionResultsCallback no longer gives me an error. The three instances of PermissionUtils does give me an error still. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SamuelJacksonJr: There is nothing named `PermissionUtils` in the Android SDK. I happened to write a class named `PermissionUtils`, but the API that you are using does not line up with mine. You will need to track down where you got this code from and figure out where it got its `PermissionUtils` from.

Comment: Got it to work after I found the PermissionUtils class. Thank you so much for your help. Very new to this and I just learned alot.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue wondering why the PermissionUtil class could not be found.The class can be found at googlemap/android-maps sample(https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/PermissionUtils.java) at Github. I simply created a java file, copied the code and replaced the string resources.